# VueJS: Dropdown on navbar doesn't work while navigate to other page

Tags: vuejs2

I have a Vue single-page-apps about a simple online bookstore. This project so far runs well except a tiny issue: When a login customer clicks 'logout' link on navbar, the system navigates him to the frontpage and 'logout' link becomes a 'register/login' link. This link should be a dropdown, but after navigating, this link doesn't work(no respond while clicking it) anymore until press F5 to reload the page from 'server'. Following is my navbar.vue

```
<template>
    ...
    <!---Good Dropdown--->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownShowMenuLink" 
                role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Showroom
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownShowMenuLink">
            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/showBookList/newAddings">By Updates</router-link>
            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/showBookList/authors">By Authors</router-link>
            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/showBookList/categories">By Categories</router-link>
        </div>
    </li>       


    <template v-if="isLogin">
        <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" id="logoutLink" href="javascript:void(0)" @click="logout">logout</a>
        </li>
        <template v-if="isAdmin">                               
            <li class="nav-item">
                <router-link class="nav-link" to="/admin">Dashboard</router-link>
            </li>                               
        </template>
    </template>
    <template v-else>   
        <!--Bad dropdown-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdownUserMenuLink" 
                role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Login/Register</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownUserMenuLink">
                <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/loginForm">Sign In</router-link>
                <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/registerForm">Sign Up</router-link>                                
            </div>
        </li>                            
    </template> 
    ...
</template>

<script>
    import configs from '@/configs'

    export default{
        ...

        methods{
            async logout(){
                let logoutURL = configs.serverURL + configs.serverPort + '/logout';
                await this.$store.dispatch('logout', {logoutURL});
                alert(this.$store.getters.currentMsg);                
                this.$router.push('/');            
            },
        },

        ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses a couple of libraries for dropdowns (jquery, popperJS and its own bootstrapJS file)...check the browser developer console for any errors with loading those libraries when a user logs out and is redirected to the front page.

Comment: I just used Chrome DevTools to debug, but unfortunately there is NO ERROR at in the console. Here is an interesting thing I forgot to mention : there's another dropdown on the navbar, it works fine after navigating. They have exactly same structure. So I guess if sth wrong with bootstrap libraries, it should affect the other dropdown too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple way to work around:

**use v-show rather than v-if to render bootstrap dropdown.**

```
           <li v-show="!isLogin" class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownUserMenuLink" 
                    role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Login/Register</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownUserMenuLink">
                    <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/loginForm">Sign In</router-link>
                    <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/registerForm">Sign Up</router-link>                                
                </div>
            </li>
```

According to guidline of Vue2:

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event listeners and child components inside the conditional block are properly destroyed and re-created during toggles. In comparison, v-show is much simpler - the element is always rendered regardless of initial condition, with CSS-based toggling.

I think sth wrong while re-creating "dropdown". Maybe someone can help me to figure out how to use "v-if".